# Sharing Code between Objective-C based SDKs

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoapods

I'm developing two Objective-C based SDKs and I have common code that I'd like to share between the two SDKs. I'd also like to be able to expose this common code to consumers of the SDKs too. For the common code that I'd like to expose to clients of the SDKs, I'd want this to be exposed to developers that are writing their apps in both Objective-C and Swift.

I was thinking of using a Cocoapod for organizing the common Objective-C based code & have started off a library with `pod lib create CommonCode`. For this CommonCode library, it's pretty easy to declare which .h files are exposed and which ones are private via the `Target Membership` options.

However, when importing this `CommonCode` cocoapod into one of the SDKs, I'm unsure of how to expose .h files in the `CommonCode` via one of the SDKs. i.e - how can I make sure that developers who are consuming one of the SDKs can get access to some of the code contained in the `CommonCode` library.

Is this possible with Cocoapods? Would you advise me on a better way to organize my code?

Answer (score 1):

It's okay to have multiple dependencies in your application, but I would strongly recommend to minimize the number of dependencies in your libraries/frameworks/SDKs.

It is important for the host application developers, because indirect dependencies could cause linkage or symbol resolution conflicts with other direct and indirect dependencies when different versions are required by different dependents.

If you need to share some code between two frameworks, consider joining them into one workspace and adding the files you're interested in to both framework targets. I would not recommend exposing any shared content publicly, because it can cause linkage or symbol resolution problems when using both of your frameworks in one application.

Also check if one of the frameworks actually depends on another — then it could make sense to just declare this dependency explicitly.

Of course, you can extract the shared code into another framework and declare this dependency explicitly — that's what you're considering in the OP. There is nothing special about this shared framework with relation to CocoaPods, prepare it as usual.

Don't worry about (in)visibility of this indirect dependency to the host application. If the host application really needs to access the shared framework, the application can import and use it explicitly.

If all of your frameworks are in Objective-C, you can try to import the umbrella header of the shared framework in the umbrella header of your main framework. If the compiler won't complain, that should do what you want.

I'm not talking about CocoaPods black magic (on-the-fly pod build settings modification) here, because I don't think you need to mess with it to solve you issue.

Comment: I see where you're coming from in relation to trying to limit the amount of external dependencies for an application. The two SDKs that I'm developing would never be incorporated into the same application though. The common code that I mentioned in the original post would need to be accessible via each separate SDK. In terms of extracting the common code into a separate framework which would be brought into each SDK - do you have any suggestions on how best to do this - do you think I'm over complicating things with cocoapods perhaps?

Comment: @seanoshea I have updated the answer to emphasize the main points. Hope you'll find it useful :)